# "Can't open file "C:" for reading; you may not have read permission." error in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, svm, imread

I have such a code;

```
for x = 1:100
    path = sprintf('C:\Users\hasan_000\Documents\MATLAB\Project\Images\%d.jpg', x);
    imgarray = imread(sprintf(path));
end
```

I have a folder involves 100 pictures. I want to convert them to matrix by uploading automatically in a loop.

But I get this error:

> Can't open file "C:" for reading;
>       you may not have read permission.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: This is strange. The `sprintf` in the second line is unnecessary, though that's not what is causing this. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: The path is C:\Users\hasan_000\Documents\MATLAB\Project\Images. For instance, C:\Users\hasan_000\Documents\MATLAB\Project\Images\1.jpg. My 100 pictures are renamed from 1 to 100 as 'number'.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code should output the warning:

> "Warning: Escape sequence '\U' is not valid. See 'help sprintf' for valid escape
>   sequences. "

You need to escape the `\` when using sprintf. With yor code `path` is `C:`. For examples how proper escaping is done, please check the documentation for `sprintf`. Instead I would use this code:

```
P=fullfile('C:\Users\hasan_000\Documents\MATLAB\Project\Images',sprintf('%d.jpg',x))
imgarray = imread(P);
```

Comment: So, what can the syntax path be Daniel?

Comment: nice touch using `fullfile`!

Answer (score 4):

`sprintf('C:\\Users\\hasan_000\\Documents\\MATLAB\\Project\\Images\\%d.jpg', x);` should solve the issue.

> sprintf('%s%d%s','C:\Users\hasan_000\Documents\MATLAB\Project\Images\',x,'.jpg');

is what I would suggest as it makes the code more intuitive and readable.

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf` does not like your backslashes `\` in the filename since it can be part of a specific command. If you simply run the path file you'll see:

```
path = sprintf('C:\Users\hasan_000\Documents\MATLAB\Project\Images\%d.jpg', 1);
```

> path = C:

So that's where your code breaks. I'm currently not sitting on a windows machine, but I'd try reversing the slashes from backslashes `\` to normal ones `/` and see if it can open that.

Second method works for sure:

```
path = ['C:\Users\hasan_000\Documents\MATLAB\Project\Images\', sprintf('%d.jpg', x)]
```

> path = C:\Users\hasan_000\Documents\MATLAB\Project\Images\1.jpg